# subjunctive form and present tense form in my sentence

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

Let's say I want to say:

```
I don't want the bank to send ads to my family.
```

In this the correct translation?

```
 No quiero que el banco envíe anuncios a mi familia.
```

If so, why `envíe` being **subjunctive** form? Why not `envía` -- **present tense** form?

Comment: Both *envíe* and *envía* are present tense.  *envíe* is also subjunctive, and *envía* is indicative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct translation because envía is the indicative mood and envíe is the subjunctive mood.  In this case, it clearly calls for the subjunctive because you are expressing a desire to influence the bank to NOT send ads to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The subjunctive is one of several **moods**, along with the indicative, imperative and conditional. The present is one of several **tenses**. *Envíe* is present tense, subjunctive mood, third person singular.

The subjunctive appears in many different contexts. One of them is in subordinate sentences (marked by *que*) whose main verb is *querer*. This also happens with *desear* "to wish" and other verbs like *gustar*, that express wishes or (dis)likes. It doesn't depend on whether the sentence is affirmative or negative:

> *Quiero que me envíes un regalo.* "I want you to send me a gift."
>   *No quiero que gastes mucho dinero.* "I don't want you to spend a lot of money."

For other verbs the subjunctive is optional, or only used in negations, or it follows other rules that I can't summarize here.

Comment: "Desire to influence' whatever the verb may be requires the use of the subjunctive mood in the subordinate clause.